# VS Extension: Add custom option page to existing option category

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I would like to place the options of my Visual Studio extension under the *Projects and Solutions* options category. Adding the attribute `[ProvideOptionPage(..., "Projects and Solutions", ...)]` will create a new *Projects and Solutions* category.

Is there any way to extend the existing?

Answer (score 0):

In `%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<Version>\Settings\` there is a file `CurrentSettings.vssettings`. Rename it to xml, open it and check out the `ToolsOptionsCategories`.